# Black and white vertices labeling

Tags: graph-theory

I'm reading [Pearls in Graph Theory by Nora Hartsfield and Gerhard Ringel](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Pearls-Graph-Theory-Comprehensive-Introduction/dp/0486432327), and the proof of theorem 8.2.5 confused me:

> Theorem   8.2.5.  If  in  a   normal  map $M$, the vertices    can be  labeled by  black   and white   so  that    around  each    country in  $M$  the number  of  black   vertices    minus   the
>   number    of  white   vertices    is  a   multiple    of  three,  then    the edges   of  $M$  can be
>   properly  colored by  three   colors.
>
> Proof.    Given   a   normal  map $M$  and a   labeling    of  the vertices    by  black   and white
>   with  the above   property,   we  construct   the normal  $M’$  by  blowing up  every   white
>   vertex    into    a   triangle    with    three   black   vertices.   So  we  have    a   map $M'$  such    that
>   all   the vertices    are black,  and all the countries   are triangles,  hexagons,   nonagons,
>   etc.  We  now color   the edges   of  $M'$  by  three   colors  as  follows.    We  begin   at  any
>   country   and walk    counterclockwise    around  the inside  of  the country and color
>   the   edges   by  $a, b, c, a, b, c, ...$  as  we  come    to  them.   The number  of  edges   around
>   each  country is  a   multiple    of  three,  so  the coloring    is  proper  so  far.    Now we
>   color a   region  adjoining   the first   region  by  the same    recipe; one edge    will
>   already   be  colored,    so  the coloring    is  determined. 
>   **To  see that    the coloring    is proper,  consider    Figure  8.2.10.**
>
> [image]
>   [image]
>
> Now   we  return  to  the map $M$  from    $M′$. As  in  Figure  8.2.8,  when    we  restore
>   a white   vertex, we  shrink  a   triangle    with    three   black   vertices,   and we  keep    the
>   coloring  of  the remaining   edges.  This    is  a   proper  coloring,   since   we  shrink  a
>   triangle  with    edges   colored $a$, $b$, and $c$, and the edges   remaining   around  the white
>   vertex    must    be  colored $a$, $b$, and $c$.

Here *normal* means connected, bridgeless, planar multigraph that is cubic.

I’m lost on the bold part -- is it guaranteed that the coloring will always be proper?

Consider a country surrounded by others, if coloring of the surrounding countries are determined, then for the country in the centre, will the coloring be automatically proper, i.e. in the good $a$,$b$,$c$ sequence?

I don't see this straightforward. Pls enlighten me.